# a simple django jquery location question

Tags: jquery, django

I'm setting up a django project for the first time and I want to use jQuery.  Is the idea that I just create a media folder, stick jquery in it and then point MEDIA_ROOT to it?  Any suggestions for a good standard location for the media folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django people very strongly recommend to put static files somewhere, where Django doesn't need to handle them. So, if your app is at example.com, serve static files from static.example.com.

If you can't do this, follow the link of the above answer. They explain it quite nicely.

Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

The [how to serve static files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) section in the Django documentation should help you get started. I tend to keep all static files for all my Django projects under `static` directory at the root of the project. I usually create a structure like this:

```
static/
   css/
   images/
   js/
   ...
```

You could place the static files anywhere you like, depending on where it is more convenient for your requirements